# python recursion function return

Tags: python, function, recursion, return

I want to make decimal-binary converter using recursion.
I've done it, but my function (below) returns None..
If I change return clause to print - it's work properly.
But I want returning here!
What's the problem?

```
def my_bin(num, result = ''): 

    if num == 0:
        return result[::-1]
    else:
        result += str(num%2)   
        my_bin(num//2, result)
       
my_bin(5) # None
```

Comment: `return my_bin(num//2, result)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One return is missing:

```py
def my_bin(num, result = ''):

    if num == 0:
        return result[::-1]
    else:
        result += str(num%2)
        return my_bin(num//2, result)

my_bin(5)
```